# What are the alternatives to Ruby Version Manager (rvm)?

Tags: ruby, version, rvm

rvm had a substantial impact on ruby programming and for a long time brought lasting benefits to us, but honestly I need to stay agile and informed about other possibilities at this point. Lately I only get one version of Ruby to manage so I'm not sure if the benefit is outweighing the cost of configuration.

One alternative, [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), has worked well for me. rbenv is an alternative because it let's us set the global ruby version on a per-user basis, and like rvm offers support for per-project Ruby versions. Also you can override the Ruby version with an environment variable. I do not know what it's like yet to use [ry](https://github.com/jayferd/ry). If anyone has used ry or the other alternatives, please share any knowledge or experience on this question I feel is important. I am always interested in things I have not heard of and knowing more about some of these alternatives to Ruby Version Manager (rvm). Also I feel grateful for Stackoverflow.com and this area of the internet's wealth of knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: time is a cost, but I dont know I am unsure about what the alternatives to RVM are

Comment: That's what I'm saying: what time? Setting up RVM requires a couple of minutes. Then it doesn't require any further configuration.

Comment: I re-installed fresh OSX 10.7 this weekend. Some trouble there with rvm running 1.9.2. I have 1.9.3 with rvm but this is maybe more symptomatic of 10.7.3 & Xcode, not really sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the list of available alternatives https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/docs/alt.md

There is one big difference between RVM and the rest of tools - RVM has big experience with a lot of corner cases, it covers many possible configurations, it is used on many different *nix distributions.

So all the small tools cover the minimalistic way of doing things, like installation:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/rubies/1.9.3
make
make install
```

Q: what prevents you from doing it ? 
A: Experience, do you know it will exactly build and run on any system you try ? RVM does just that it tries to provide you one way to install on every system.

The mentioned ruby 1.9.3 will most likely compile just fine, but for example you can use patches, RVM does provide already many patches, few of them are installed automatically to solve compilation/building issues, like ruby 1.8.7 or 1.8.6.

But there are other things, you want to use JRuby on production (it happens to be faster) so you need to test it ... in 1.9 mode ? that's easy just say to RVM to use 1.9 mode:

```
rvm install jruby-1.6.7 --1.9
```

now it will be by default using 1.9 mode and trust me getting there is not that easy - at least for now.

There is a lot of things which RVM does to you and for you, with latest development version you can use other project files not only `.rvmrc` -> https://gist.github.com/1912050#gistcomment-86549 you could play for example using `.ruby-version` project file which is already supported by [rbfu](https://github.com/hmans/rbfu) and always get back to RVM if you feel like you need more.

Comment: Thank you mpapis, great answer. Seems like there may be some efforts to make version managers compatible. Also looking into this discussion is interesting, especially https://github.com/kwatch/versionswitcher

Comment: how cool is this http://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv

Comment: @BentCardan be careful with `autoenv`, it has the same limitations as `.rvmrc` -> check this comment https://gist.github.com/1912050#gistcomment-86657

Comment: Good thing to know, mpapis. I am cautiously excited about autoenv. Don't need it playing with my cd alias, but autoenv represents a new form of project control. Just buckle the seat-belt on all server side scripting languages throughout the course of your project. It's a great idea. I mean who else hasn't toyed with the idea of mixing some python scripts, or even just php to help out something like a sinatra app.. for example this would definitely help keep that type of environment stable over the course development, testing and deployment. I mean I just picture autoenv fueling agility

Comment: I think one big disadvantage of rvm is it overrides cd. It makes open a terminal tab extremely slow. So why is this autoenv so good?

Comment: @yiwen rvm shoul load way bellow 1 second, if it loads longer please open a ticket for it